# Runner not picking up on the yml file

Tags: spring-boot, maven, github, continuous-integration

```
name: ci-cd

on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Build with Maven
        run:
          cd Backend/hellopeople
          mvn test
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: artifact
          path: Backend/target/*.jar
```

this is my yml file for some reason even if I push my code the runner doesnt try to build it

is there an issue with my runner or is it my yml file?

Comment: First why `cd Backend/hellopeople` second what your runner is doing or not I simply don't know...without even a log file or a link to your project or even better posting the log output here...  Also you are using very old actions instaed of `actions/checkout@v3` and why are you uploading artifacts for which workflow actioN?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am not sure what I am doing tbh Github runners are new to me. I am trying to have 2 stages one that builds the maven project. The maven project part is only the back end thus if I try to build the entire thing then It will cause issues. The 2nd part I am trying to see if the generated jar file runs without issues.

Comment: my target folder is in Backend/hellopeople and my maven project is the hellopeople folder.

Comment: If github runners a new to you why are using a self hosted one? `runs-on: self-hosted` That's the point. That means you are using a self hosted runner which is not public... so you are not using the default existing runners on GitHub ... I know what your yml file describes but is your runner not triggered, log file/error message? `if I push my code the runner doesnt try to build it` what does that mean? Trigger? You runner is wrongly configured ? Do you have a log file of the runner? Does your project build on plain command line ? Why do you need to cd in to a sub directory etc. ?